# Reduce coefficients from constraints in a set of equations

Tags: equation-solving, simplifying-expressions, symbolic, polynomials

Total beginner here. I am chaining 4 quadratic equations $f_i(x)$ at 4 knots $k_i$ (where $0 < k_i < 1$ and $k_{i+1} > k_i$) on a wrapped unit interval (i.e. $0 \leq x \leq 1$):

$$ f_i(x) = a_i x^2 + b_i x + c_i, \quad k_i < x \leq k_{i+1}, \quad i = 0 \dots 3, $$

with connectivity and phase-wrapping constraints:

$$ f_i(k_{i+1}) = f_{i+1}(k_{i+1})\ \ \textrm{for }\ i = 0 \dots 2 \ \textrm{and}\  f_3(k_0+1)=f_0(k_0). $$

Given that I have 12 coefficients ($a_0 \dots a_3, b_0 \dots b_3, c_0 \dots c_3$) and 4 constraints, I'd like to compute expressions for (any) 8 independent coefficients, say $a_0 \dots a_3,$ $b_0 \dots b_2$ and $c_0$. I thought that Mathematica's `Reduce` would do the trick, but it just keeps running indefinitely. Any suggestions on how I'd approach this?

Here's my feeble attempt:

```
f0[x_] = a0 x^2 + b0 x + c0
f1[x_] = a1 x^2 + b1 x + c1
f2[x_] = a2 x^2 + b2 x + c2
f3[x_] = a3 x^2 + b3 x + c3
Reduce[f0[k1] == f1[k1] && f1[k2] == f2[k2] && f2[k3] == f3[k3] && 
  f3[k0 + 1] == f0[k0] && k1 != 0 && k2 != 0 && k3 != 0 && 
  k4 != 0, {a0, b0, c0, a1, b1, a2, b2, a3}]
```

Comment: Include the actual code that you used.

Comment: You can not solve 4 equations for 8 unknowns. Further, the solution set seems pretty complicated and it may be, that only implicit solutions are possible, that is not var=.., but fun[vars]==0.

Comment: I'm not looking for a unique solution -- I'm looking for /a/ solution; that is certainly possible and I can work it out by hand. I'd just like to have mathematica do that for me instead of spending 45 min to write it out myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I just needed to expand the list of coefficients to a full list:

```
f0[x_] = a0 x^2 + b0 x + c0
f1[x_] = a1 x^2 + b1 x + c1
f2[x_] = a2 x^2 + b2 x + c2
f3[x_] = a3 x^2 + b3 x + c3
Reduce[f0[k1] == f1[k1] && f1[k2] == f2[k2] && f2[k3] == f3[k3] && 
  f3[k0 + 1] == f0[k0] && k1 != 0 && k2 != 0 && k3 != 0 && 
  k4 != 0, {a0, b0, c0, a1, b1, c1, a2, b2, c2, a3, b3, c3}]
```

With that change I got what I needed.

Comment: Specifying the domain `Reals` in your original `Reduce` yields a result, too.